# Visual Studio: ignore undefined references in shared libraries

Tags: visual-c++, dll, compiler-construction, linker, shared-libraries

I wish to compile a project that makes use of a shared library, but I do not have access to the original lib files. I do however, have the original interface...

All I basically want is to have the compiler do symbol name mangling etc. so I don't have to manually call into GetProcAddress...

Visual Studio however, complains about undefined references (duh) when I don't link against the shared lib.... With GNU LD I could use 'allow-shlib-undefined' but unfortunately I must make use of MSVC++... Is there something similar?

edit:

Of course, I could make a fake (proxy) dll, create stubs for all the methods found in my interface, link against that, and then load the original dll. I don't know if that's the best solution though...

edit2:

Looks like I can just export symbols and generate a lib file:
http://www.coderetard.com/2009/01/21/generate-a-lib-from-a-dll-with-visual-studio/

I'll try that first and report back.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to investigate ["Edll for Windows"](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/edll.htm) ([home](http://edll.sourceforge.net/)) implementation:

> EnhancedDLL -- to have plugins and libraries with undefined symbols

It discovers 4 solutions to overcome DLL limitations: ["The usual solution"](http://edll.sourceforge.net/#usual), ["The sub-DLL solution"](http://edll.sourceforge.net/#sub_dll), ["The .def &.a solution"](http://edll.sourceforge.net/#def_a) and ["The edll solution"](http://edll.sourceforge.net/#edll).

Comment: I already managed to hack it in by using objdump to dump exports and then using a def file to generate a lib file. Looks a lot like your 3rd solution... Upvote & accept for being the only one to answer and providing a decent answer for anyone that needs it in the future.